# How to plot random effects of cross-classified logistic multilevel model in R?

Tags: r, data-visualization

I estimated a cross-classified logistic mixed model in R, with two types of level-2 subjects: 34 election dates and 408 municipalities. The level 1 observations are aggregated proportions of the voter turnout (dependent) and 2 independent variables. Then there are some characteristics on the election dates and some controls. I estimated cross-level interactions between the main independent variables and the types of elections (macro-level characteristic of election date). Therefore, the effects were estimated as random over election dates. Now I would like to plot the random effects: 34 regression lines in a plot, being of 4 different colors (according to the macro-level: the different types of elections).

Does anyone know how to plot such a thing in R?

UPDATE:
Thanks for the hints! I'm quite new to R. I know how to estimate my models, but apart from that I still have a lot to learn.

This is my final model. 
"gemnr" is the municipality level.
"Date" is the election date I was talking about. 
"Windchill" and "Rain" are the random effects over "Date", and are interacted with three types of elections "Provincie" "Gemeente" and "Europa". The rest of the variables are controls.
The dependent variable is the real proportion of voters: cbind(opkomst, nnietgestemd), which stands for the number of votes(opkomst) and the number of non-voters (nnietgestemd).

```
# Model with controls and interactions.
model3b <- glmer (cbind(opkomst, nnietgestemd) ~
       (1|gemnr)+(1+Windchill+Rain|Date) + Windchill + Windspeed + Rain + SP + lag_popkomst + Provincie + Gemeente + Europa + NB + OL + loginw 
       + Provincie:Windchill + Gemeente:Windchill + Europa:Windchill + Provincie:Rain + Gemeente:Rain + Europa:Rain, family=binomial(link=logit))
```

And this is the result:

```
Generalized linear mixed model fit by maximum likelihood ['glmerMod']
 Family: binomial ( logit )
Formula: cbind(opkomst, nnietgestemd) ~ (1 | gemnr) + (1 + Windchill +      Rain | Date) + Windchill + Windspeed + Rain + SP + lag_popkomst +      Provincie + Gemeente + Europa + NB + OL + loginw + Provincie:Windchill +      Gemeente:Windchill + Europa:Windchill + Provincie:Rain +      Gemeente:Rain + Europa:Rain 

      AIC       BIC    logLik  deviance 
1452503.3 1452691.4 -726226.6 1452453.3 

Random effects:
 Groups Name        Variance  Std.Dev. Corr       
 gemnr  (Intercept) 0.0146186 0.12091             
 Date   (Intercept) 0.1902650 0.43619             
        Windchill   0.0009727 0.03119  -0.07      
        Rain        0.0103655 0.10181   0.59 -0.10
Number of obs: 13735, groups: gemnr, 408; Date, 34

Fixed effects:
                       Estimate  Std. Error z value             Pr(>|z|)    
(Intercept)         -0.23067667  0.12124970    -1.9             0.057107 .  
Windchill           -0.00768949  0.00834125    -0.9             0.356600    
Windspeed            0.01040831  0.00017884    58.2 < 0.0000000000000002 ***
Rain                -0.00157012  0.02908864    -0.1             0.956953    
SP                   0.00045626  0.00001432    31.9 < 0.0000000000000002 ***
lag_popkomst         2.10911785  0.00386440   545.8 < 0.0000000000000002 ***
Provincie           -1.09414033  0.25162607    -4.3     0.00001372100383 ***
Gemeente            -0.60849053  0.18353633    -3.3             0.000915 ***
Europa              -1.21169484  0.21694178    -5.6     0.00000002332356 ***
NB                   0.07397575  0.01053297     7.0     0.00000000000217 ***
OL                   0.00288172  0.00821660     0.4             0.725799    
loginw              -0.10297623  0.00721768   -14.3 < 0.0000000000000002 ***
Windchill:Provincie  0.01743852  0.01769197     1.0             0.324293    
Windchill:Gemeente   0.01010439  0.01292002     0.8             0.434172    
Windchill:Europa     0.01664707  0.01522839     1.1             0.274323    
Rain:Provincie      -0.13692131  0.05956872    -2.3             0.021531 *  
Rain:Gemeente       -0.03330741  0.04340056    -0.8             0.442819    
Rain:Europa         -0.04864840  0.05142619    -0.9             0.344156    
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1
```

Comment: use `expand.grid` and `merge` to generate a complete, balanced set of predictors (if your original predictors are not complete); then use `predict` (I'm assuming here you're using a recent version of `lme4`) to generate predictions at the appropriate level; then use `ggplot` to plot the results with the `group` aesthetic set to "election date" and the `colour` aesthetic set to "type" ...

Comment: PS if you give a minimal reproducible example I'll try to demonstrate ...