# Plotting multiple probabilities of an logistic multilevel model

Tags: r, ggplot2, logistic-regression, lme4, multi-level

I need to estimate and plot a logistic multilevel model. I've got the binary dependent variable employment status (empl) (0 = unemployed; 1 = employed) and level of internet connectivity (isoc) as (continuous) independent variable and need to include random effects (intercept and slope) alongside the education level (educ) (1 = low-skilled worker; 2 = middle-skilled; 3 = high-skilled). Also I have some control variables I'm not going to mention here. I'm using the **glmer** function of the **lme4** package. Here is a sample data frame and my (simplified) code:

```r
library(lme4)
library(lmerTest)
library(tidyverse)
library(dplyr)
library(sjPlot)
library(moonBook)
library(sjmisc)
library(sjlabelled)

set.seed(1212)
d <- data.frame(empl=c(1,1,1,0,1,0,1,1,0,1,1,1,0,1,0,1,1,1,1,0), 
      isoc=runif(20, min=-0.2, max=0.2), 
      educ=sample(1:3, 20, replace=TRUE))
```

Results:

```
   empl         isoc educ
1     1  0.078604108    1
2     1  0.093667591    3
3     1 -0.061523272    2
4     0  0.009468908    3
5     1 -0.169220134    2
6     0 -0.038594789    3
7     1  0.170506490    1
8     1 -0.098487991    1
9     0  0.073339737    1
10    1  0.144211813    3
11    1 -0.133510687    1
12    1 -0.045306606    3
13    0  0.124211903    3
14    1 -0.003908486    3
15    0 -0.080673475    3
16    1  0.061406993    3
17    1  0.015401951    2
18    1  0.073351501    2
19    1  0.075648137    2
20    0  0.041450192    1
```

Fit:

```r
m <- glmer(empl ~ isoc + (1 + isoc | educ),
            data=d,
            family=binomial("logit"),
            nAGQ = 0)
summary(m)
```

Now the question: I'm looking for a plot with three graphs, one graph for each educ-level, with the probabilities (values just between 0 and 1). Here is an sample image from the web: [image]

Below is my (simplified) code for the plot. But it only produces crap I cannot interpret.

```
plot_model(m, type="pred",
           terms=c("isoc [all]", "educ"),
           show.data=TRUE)
```

There is one thing I can do to get a "kind-of" right plot but I have to alter the model above in a way I think it's wrong (keyword: multicollinearity). Additionally I don't think the three graphs of this plot are correct either. The modified model looks like this:

```
m <- glmer(empl ~ isoc + educ (1 + isoc | educ),
            data=d,
            family=binomial("logit"),
            nAGQ = 0)
summary(m)
```

I appreciate any help! I think my problem resembles [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21223674/how-to-plot-random-effects-of-cross-classified-logistic-multilevel-model-in-r) but unfortunately there has been no answer to this yet and unfortunately I'm not able to comment with my low reputation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you want

```r
plot_model(m, type="pred", 
      pred.type = "re", 
      terms = c("isoc[n=100]","educ"), show.data = TRUE)
```

- `pred.type = "re"` takes the random effects into account when making predictions
- `isoc[n=100]` uses 100 distinct values across the range of `isoc` - this is better than making predictions only at the *observed* values of `isoc`, which is what `[all]` specifies

For the example you've given the prediction lines are all on top of each other (because the fit is singular/the random-effects variance is effectively zero), but that's presumably because your sample data set is so small.

---

For what it's worth, although this is a perfectly well-posed programming problem, I would **not** recommend treating `educ` as a random effect:

- the number of levels is impractically small
- the levels are not **exchangeable** (i.e. it wouldn't make sense to relabel "high-skilled" as "low-skilled").

Feel free to ask more questions about your model setup/definition on [CrossValidated](https://stats.stackexchange.com)

Comment: Hi @BenBolker, thanks for your answer, this worked for me. I think I see your point with treating ´educ` as a random effect. But for the sake of simplicity and to be able to finish my term paper I need to keep it like this. I will check the CrossValidated page!